# Android emulator instant closing after starting up

Tags: android, nativescript, android-virtual-device

I created new project.

When I'm doing `tns device --available-devices`. Everything seems to be ok.

```
Available emulators
┌─────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────┐
│ Device Name │ Platform │ Version │ Device Identifier │ Image Identifier │ Error Help │
│ test        │ Android  │ 7.1.1   │                   │ test             │            │
└─────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────┘
```

When I'm doing `tns run android`, something is fast opening and closing (~1sec).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Svkiyo/0a3b022808f4e3855092ff0f25a3c5e2) is `tns run android --log trace`

I'm totally new, I tryied a lot of things from others but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstall the emulator maybe it causes cache issues
& personally I suggest you use your mobile as an emulator which is more efficient

1. Connect the USB cable between mobile and pc/laptop
2. enable developer options from your mobile
3. enable USB debugging

boom, now you are ready to test your app

Comment: Ok thanks, isn't that a little slow to develop? For ex: Just for a simple CSS modification ?

Comment: It's based on your PC/Laptop configuration buddy